# Is there a web application out on the web somewhere that can test apache conf files? Something like JSFiddle for Apache?

Tags: testing, web-applications, apache

Many of us use jsfiddle.com to share DHTML situations with other people. You can include plugins like JQuery while testing. it's very convenient, especially when posting to stackoverflow.com.

I am interested in something like that for Apache httpd. Does it exist?

Here is a diagram of what I'm thinking of. You can imagine all the things that you could do with this.

[image: Apache Conf Tester App]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not exist anywhere. I am working on this project starting two weeks ago.